# Android: Avoid view invalidate when only layout is changed

Tags: android, listview

When animating height of an item in `ListView`, the `setViewValue()` method in the `ViewBinder` is called several times for each layout change, making the animation very slow.

I am currently solving it by setting a `disableViewUpdate` flag in `onAnimationStart()` and turning it off in `onAnimationEnd()`. `setViewValue()` returns `true` if the flag is set, avoiding any database lookup. But there are still tens or hundreds of calls to `setViewValue()` during each animation step.

My question is: Is there a way to avoid `setViewValue()` being called as a result of layout changes?

Answer (score 0):

I would just go for inheriting from ListView, overriding the method and then avoiding any action when the method is called and the view is animating.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Which method should I override? I tried both requestLayout() and isLayoutRequested(), but none is useful for preventing setViewValue() in the ViewBinder to be called. I also tried to call postInvalidateDelayed(long delayMilliseconds), but without success.